# How can I find out what is causing a certain URL to be resolved to a synthetic resources?

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

On my Adobe CQ 5 (CQ 5.6) installation, for some reason, there's a URL (`http://localhost:4503/services`) that is getting resolved to a synthetic resource:

[image: /services is resolved to a synthetic resource]

This is causing CQ to show the following page, rather than a 404 Page Not Found page:

[image: Forbidden response when accessing /services]

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `Forbidden` error not because of the strange type of the `/services`, but because you didn't add any extension (you'll get the same result requesting `/content/geometrixx`). Let's try to add some extension: `.html` doesn't really work, but `.infinity.tidy.json` results in interesting discovery:

```
{
  "tagfilter": {
    "sling:resourceType": "/services/tagfilter.servlet",
    "servletClass": "com.adobe.cq.social.commons.impl.servlets.TagFilterServlet",
    "sling:resourceSuperType": "sling/bundle/resource",
    "servletName": "com.adobe.cq.social.commons.impl.servlets.TagFilterServlet"
  },
  "tagfilter.servlet": {
    "sling:resourceType": "/services/tagfilter.servlet",
    "servletClass": "com.adobe.cq.social.commons.impl.servlets.TagFilterServlet",
    "sling:resourceSuperType": "sling/bundle/resource",
    "servletName": "com.adobe.cq.social.commons.impl.servlets.TagFilterServlet"
  },
  ...
```

It seems that `/services` is a *virtual* (or, well, *synthetic*) path, a parent for servlets. In fact, you can't bind servlet to any path, the most popular choice is `/bin` prefix, however `/services` is possible as well. You'll find a list of all such paths in **Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver and Error Handler** OSGi configuration.