# Identifying Synthetic Resources in CQ5 / AEM

Tags: aem, sling

**TLDR**: How do I identify all the Synthetic resources that are defined in an AEM instance?

**Issue**:
I have a `cq:Page` named `xyz` under `/content` and a URL mapping defined in *Apache Sling JCR Resource Resolver* as `/content/:/`

Accessing the page as `http://<server>:<port>/content/xyz.html` or `http://<server>:<port>/xyz/_jcr_content.html` works fine, however accessing the same as `http://<server>:<port>/xyz.html` gives me 404.

Accessing the same using `.json` extension gives `{ }` and using `.infinity.json` gives **Resource not adaptable to node: /xyz (500)**

Resolving the path through Sling Resource Resolver shows
`SyntheticResource, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/xyz` and according to the Sling's Documentation accessing a Synthetic resource would result in a 404.

1. However the question is, 
   would a Synthetic resource take precedence before the URL mappings are applied?
2. If that is the case, then how do i identify where such a resource is defined, and what other such resources are available?

I have already gone through [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834912/how-can-i-find-out-what-is-causing-a-certain-url-to-be-resolved-to-a-synthetic-r), however the solution provided isn't complete or rather only discusses the same things as described above.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am getting SyntheticResource when using mapping via /etc/map